# Retornar data correta strtotime php

Tags: php, strtotime

Tenho a seguinte linha

```
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime("28/09/2016")); // 1970-01-01
```

Como eu faço pra retornar 2016-09-28? Se o dia for menor que 12, retorna certinho...

Comment: a string dentro do `strtotime` tem que ter o separador com `-` também, tente isso.

Comment: O engraçado é que se eu colocar um dia menor do que 12 meses, retorna normal

Comment: Era isso Rafael, echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime(str_replace("/", "-", "28/09/2016"))); obrigado amigo. Me chama no skype K7, você some!

Comment: Posta como resposta, pra dar o aceite aqui.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você precisa passar como parametro para o `strtotime` uma string com separador usando `-` (hífen) por exemplo;

```
$date = str_replace("/", "-", "28/09/2016");
echo date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date));
```

Answer (score 5):

Pode fazer usando o objeto `DateTime` do PHP:

```
$formato = 'd/m/Y'; // define o formato de entrada para dd/mm/yyyy
$data = DateTime::createFromFormat($formato, "28/09/2016"); // define data desejada
echo $data->format('Y-m-d'); // formata a saída
```

Leia mais sobre os formatos suportados em [PHP - DATE](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.date.php)